# Scale UI buttons and images with screen size

Tags: unity-game-engine, screen, scale

I ma developing a game for unity and i want to be able to scale my buttons and UI elements to fit different screen sizes. Please how can i go about this? I have tried scale with screen size and it doesn't seem to help me. Is there a script i can use for this?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You can get the screen size easily enough https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Screen.html. Then write some logic to scale Ui element appropriately. As the bot said in the comments though we'll need more info to help you better.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use a [canvas scaler](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.ugui@1.0/manual/script-CanvasScaler.html) for this.

[image: Canvas scaler in inspector]

You simply attach this object to your canvas parenting your UI elements and it will scale them acordingly.

You will also want to make sure your UI elements are [anchored](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.ugui@1.0/manual/UIBasicLayout.html#:%7E:text=the%20Scene%20View.-,Anchors,-Rect%20Transforms%20include) correctly so that they stretch with their correct anchor point.